# Can I use Firebase Auth or FaceBook Account kit instead of SMSprovider?

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, facebook-sdk-4.0, sms-gateway

I'm using MySQL database and want to add mobile verification feature to my android app and keep using a password for login .. is that possible to use the Firebase Auth or facebook account kit as SMS provider?
if not what's the best SMS provider that provide a good service with low cost?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use facebook account kit and Firebase Auth, but i highly recommend to use facebook account kit as your are intrested in low cost, facebook account kit provides 100000 sms per month free.

You can check all details here [Facebook Account Kit Details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/overview/)